# Accessing class data from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wcf, class

I've got two windows. In the **first** window I insert data into the class `QuoteData` with the coding below

```
using (TruckServiceClient client = new TruckServiceClient())
{
     quoteFinalize = await client.GetQuoteAsync(new QuoteData
     {
         BodyTypeId = cmbBodyType.GetDisplayItemId(),
         ChassisId = cmbChassisCab.GetDisplayItemId(),
         FloorId = cmbFloorSpecification.GetDisplayItemId(),
         ExternalLength = externalLength,
         ExternalWidth = externalWidth,
         ExternalHeight = externalHeight
});
```

Then in the **second** window I want to access that same class (`QuoteData`) that I inserted data into and then set the `ExternalLength` of `QuoteData` to my label called `lblExternalLengthAmount`.

Example: `lblExternalLengthAmount.Content = ExternalLength;`

I've tried to create a new instance of `QuoteData` on the second window, but all of the values are then resest to *null*.

Is there a way to access these values? Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, it is. You have to use static class.

Comment: You would need to set it up in an either static form or within some sort of static container/collection and it would be good to use the lock statement when accessing it to keep your modifications thread safe.

Comment: Take a step back and try and implement a design pattern would be my advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the Window1 object in constructor to Window2

Window1.xaml.cs

```
 Window2 dialog = new Window2(this);//this is current window(Window1) object
```

and in Window2.xaml.cs

```
public Window2(Window1 obj)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            //obj is your Window1 object
        }
```

Any change made to obj will reflect to the Window1 also

Comment: This is not two way communication. A better what may be to pass a func<Window1> into the constructor that is stored and returns window1 but if you store it in a field it no longer is window1 but a different window1 instance. Or better yet, func<QuoteData>.

Comment: It is not a new instance of Window1. It will be the same instance. and if I write a func<Window1> how am I supposed to call that function? Is that a Window2 function or Window1? Or how will that function get the instance of Window1 from Window2? again the same thing, you need to create an instance and call which will not give you the same instance data. In such a case you need to make the function which returns Window1 instance as static. Making a function static is not correct.

Comment: `Func<Window1> getWin = new Func<Window1>(() => { return this; }); Window2 win2 = new Window2(getWin1); public Window2(Func<WIndow1> getWin1) { this.GetWindow1 = getWin1; }` There you go. The above code will return the original window 1. I assume I don't need to tell you how to call a Func delegate. ;)

Comment: @Akansha - It works perfectly, thank you very much! I didn't even need to use the class.

Comment: @CalebB As far as I know your code does the same thing. Post it like an answer if you think is a better solution

Comment: The difference is reference type. When you store Window1 in Window2 you are copying the reference to Window1 since Window1 is an object(Properties are a whole other story) thus Window1 will never be collected even if it's closed until Window2 is collected verse passing a delegate that returns Window1 will obtain Window1 without holding a strong reference to the object. Good solution all the same though so cheers. :)